# In Dragon Age: Inquisition, can I have a Chest where I can put items?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

As you know, in Dragon Age: Inquisition you can have only 60 items in your bag (some more with Inquisition Perks).

I just want to know if in Skyhold I can have a chest where I can put more items, like how we can do at the bonefire in Dark Souls 2.

I'd like to save Unique Items.

Thanks

Comment: Just FYI, you can buy inventory space in the Inquisition Perks, under the Inquisition tab. If you're at Skyhold you should be able to buy it by then.

Comment: To add to the above comment, you can purchase this ability twice. Each time you gain 15 additional slots for a total of 30 additional slots which will bring your inventory total to 90.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, [patch 5 has added a storage mechanic to the game](http://blog.bioware.com/2015/03/02/dragon-age-inquisition-patch-5-notes/).

In the Undercroft of Skyhold, where you manage your weapons and armor, there is a chest where you can store up to 1000 items. You can only store weapons, armor, accessories and upgrades.

---

Prior to patch 5 at the beginning of March 2015, there was no storage mechanic in Dragon Age: Inquisition.

BioWare had confirmed on November 19, 2014 that they knew DA:I players were requesting the feature, but hadn't made any promises.

[QA member Bryan Johnson](http://www.examiner.com/article/bioware-responds-to-fan-requests-for-storage-dragon-age-inquisition):

> "We have noticed this is a fan want. Not sure if it will happen, but it has been acknowledged we have seen it."